# Build 3d Matrix from Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and have a rather basic question.

I want to rearrange this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "sm1_wf1": [6, 6.1, 5.9, 6],
  "sm1_wf2": [7, 7.1, 6.9, 7],
  "sm2_wf1": [13, 12.9, 13.1, 13]
  "sm1_wf2":[4, 3.9, 4.1, 4]})
```

so that each row becomes a 2x2 matrix (row name will be sm1 and sm2, while column name will be wf1 and wf2), and a total of four 2x2 matrices (one for each row in the original df).
I know this could be done manually, but I want some more efficient way since the actual data has many observations.

Could someone please show me how to do that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question what format you want these 2x2 matrices in, but here is maybe one way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "sm1_wf1": [6, 6.1, 5.9, 6],
  "sm1_wf2": [7, 7.1, 6.9, 7],
  "sm2_wf1": [13, 12.9, 13.1, 13],
  "sm2_wf2": [4, 3.9, 4.1, 4]  # <-- note I changed this column name
})

# Keep original index to keep 2x2 matrices distinct
df = df.reset_index().melt("index")

# Split smX_wfY into two columns sm and wf, then join back onto data
labels = df.pop("variable").str.split("_", expand=True)
labels.columns = ["sm", "wf"]
df = labels.join(df)

# Restructure to 2x2 matrices
df.pivot_table("value", ["index", "sm"], "wf")
```

This gives:

```
wf          wf1  wf2
index sm            
0     sm1   6.0  7.0
      sm2  13.0  4.0
1     sm1   6.1  7.1
      sm2  12.9  3.9
2     sm1   5.9  6.9
      sm2  13.1  4.1
3     sm1   6.0  7.0
      sm2  13.0  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply.
I tried your solution and I noticed that the result matrix has a dimension of 2. I know maybe I wasn't clear about my question, but how can I make this a 2x2x4 matrix instead of 2x8? Thanks again.

Comment: Using pandas, data is expressed 2-dimensionally. If you are working with higher-dimensioned matrices, I'd recommend working more directly with numpy, which pandas is built on. To access the numpy array under the dataframe use `.values`. For example, to convert the data in the last step to a matrix with the dimensions you specified, try `df.values.reshape((2, 2, 4))`. I'd also recommend looking into the package xarray if you want numpy functionality with pandas indexing.